# Prove that series converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show if series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ has a positive terms and converge then the series  $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ converge too.

I don't have idea what to use here, I'd be greatful for any hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: By the AM-GM inequality, we have that $\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\le\frac{1}{2}(a_n+\frac{1}{n^2})$

Answer (score 1):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n} \leq \sqrt{\zeta(2)\sum a_n}.$$

Comment: It is interesting to notice that this bound is always better than the bound $$\sum\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\leq\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum a_n$$ given by the AM-GM inequality.