# Given that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges, show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges and $x_n \ge 0$, show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{n}$ converges.

I tried showing it as follows:

Since $x_n$ is positive it must be the case that $(x_n)$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence, then $x_n > x_{n+1}$. We'll show that $\left(\frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{n}\right)$ is a monotonically decrasing sequence with a lower bound of $0$, and therefore, converges.

Since $x_n > 0 \to \sqrt{x_n} > 0 \to \frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{n} > 0$, therefore it is bounded bellow by $0$.

Now all we have to show is that $\frac{\sqrt{x_{n+1}}}{n+1} \le \frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{n}$:

$\frac{\sqrt{x_{n+1}}}{n+1} \le \frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{n}$

$\frac{\sqrt{x_{n+1}}}{n+1} - \frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{n} \le 0$

$-n\sqrt{x_{n+1}} + n\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x_n} \ge 0$

$n(\sqrt{x_n}- \sqrt{x_{n+1}} ) + \sqrt{x_n} \ge 0$

Since $n>0 \land \sqrt{x_n}>0\land\sqrt{x_{n+1}}>0$

if $\sqrt{x_n}- \sqrt{x_{n+1}} \ge 0 \to n(\sqrt{x_n}- \sqrt{x_{n+1}} ) + \sqrt{x_n} \ge 0$

but

$\sqrt{x_n}- \sqrt{x_{n+1}} \ge 0 \iff \sqrt{x_n} \ge \sqrt{x_{n+1}} \iff x_n \ge x_{n+1}$

Since $x_n \ge x_{n+1}$ we have shown that $\left(\frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{n}\right)$ converges.

---

But as is the case with the harmonic series, this is not enough to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{n}$ converges. I tried solving it using the comparison test but I'm having a hard time showing that $\frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{n} \le cx_n$ (I don't even know how to tackle showing this inequality).

Note:

Also in my attempt above I've assumed that it is the case that $(x_n)$ must be monotonically decreasing, but I'm not sure if this is true.

Comment: $(x_n)$ need not be decreasing. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163441/if-the-series-sum-0-infty-a-n-converges-then-so-does-sum-1-infty-frac, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045443/prove-that-series-converge, or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112579/if-sum-n-1-infty-a-n2-converges-then-so-does-sum-n-1-infty-f  for correct solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Cauchy's inequality

$\sum_n\frac{\sqrt{x_n}}{n}\leq\Big(\sum_n x_n\Big)^{1/2}\Big(\sum_n\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)^{1/2}
$

I leave the details for the OP